# Jest testing in react native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

[image]

I am new to jest testing. I got this error while performing jest testing. What is the error about? And how can we solve this error? Here is my JSON file.
[image]

Comment: Without the slightest domain knowledge: This is, strictly spoken, no error,is it? It is just that the regular expression apparently didn't match anything, perhaps because the wrong path is inspected, or because it is simply erroneous.

Comment: Yes, building on Peter's comment, can you also include the `jest` property in your package.json, as well as where your tests are? That way we can see which directories jest is looking for tests in and how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Regex in testMatch is saying, that with a given setup you should put Jest tests into similarly looking folders, so Jest could find them:

```
/ __tests__/ featureA/ whatShouldFeatureADo.js
/ __tests__/ featureB/ testSuiteA/ whatShouldFeatureBDo.js
```

or you can put in everywhere you want (under the src folder), but you need to use the suffix ".test" in the filename, such as:

```
something.test.js
something.spec.js
```

*If you are using Typescript, you need to replace ".js" with ".ts" (or ".tsx" if you are testing RN components)*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, making __tests__ folder helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Comment: I ran into the above error.